# How to find the LAST sub-field after splitting a column

Tags: awk

I am trying to get the last sub-field of a string after split is applied to it. Problem is there when I do not know what is the value of last field in the spitted result.

For example Sample data

```
hey,there,how,are,you:bla:bla:foo:bar
hey,this,is ,meaningless,text,and ,the,field,are,more:zoo,zoo
hello,folks,thanks,example:is:this:is:a:line:and:I:could:not:think:of:dummy:data
```

Now I can get the last field by using NF.

Example:

```
awk -F, '{print $NF}' input
you:bla:bla:foo:bar
more:zoo,zoo
example:is:this:is:a:line:and:I:could:not:think:of:dummy:data
```

Now if I can get any field using `split` function:

```
awk -F, '{split($NF,a,":");print a[1]}' input
you
more
example
```

Now I do not want Nth field, I need to extract the **LAST** sub-field of Nth field.

So my desired output is :

```
bar
zoo
data
```

Note that something like following is **NOT** helpful as this is only helpful for last column.

```
sed -r 's/(^.*:)(.*)/\2/g' inut
bar
zoo
data
```

Comment: I can get the first column or second or so on...I need to get the LAST, something like NF for coumns, need something to use inside split.

Comment: yes.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the return value from the `split()` function and use it as the array subscript,

```
awk -F, '{n=split($NF,a,":");print a[n]}' file
bar
zoo
data
```

The return value is the number of fields split by the de-limiter `:`, which you can apply to any character of your choice.

Quoting from the [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) page for `split()` function

> *split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])*
>
> If ***fieldsep*** is a single space, then any leading whitespace goes into seps[0] and any trailing whitespace goes into seps[n], **where n is the return value of split()** (i.e., the number of elements in array).

Comment: Never thought that split also return the number of fields. Great help!!

Comment: @PS.: Glad it helps!

Comment: @Inian-  If requirement is to find the last column and we know the FS. Just curios to know why don't we use only FS.

   `awk -F'[:,]' '{print $NF}' f`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR In OP: _Now I do not want Nth field, I need to extract the LAST sub-field of Nth field_

Comment: @JamesBrown - Just tried couple of example and clarified my doubt, if we have multiple column with different counts of sub column then printing a column number can produce wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it *sdrawkcab* using `rev`, ie. get the first of the first:

```
$ rev file | awk -F, '{split($1,a,":");print a[1]}' | rev
bar
zoo
data
```

I'd still do it like @Inian.

Comment: For a second there, I thought you brought in a new construct of the air with _sdrawkcab_ spelt! Nice trick though! But Ed hates multiple tools usage with `awk` unless needed

Answer (score 1):

solution of @inian is more generic, 2 alternative specific to your 5th field and LAST sub-element.
In both case, i assume there is no noisy ';' or ':' (escaped or in string) like in your data sample.

sed version (assuming 5th field)

```
sed 's/^\([^;]*\)\{5\}[^;]*:\([^;]*\).*/\2/' YourFile
```

awk version (without split)

```
 awk -F ',' '{ sub( /.*:/, "", $5); print $5}'
```